# Why is Pr(A | (B and C)) = Pr(A | C) if A and B are independent?

Tags: probability

Why is Pr(A | (B and C)) = Pr(A | C) if A and B are independent?

We know,  that Pr(A|B) = Pr(A) if A and B are independent.

But why is Pr(A | (B and C)) = Pr(A | C) for independent events A and B ?

Comment: You will need some additional assumptions.

Comment: @HartoSaarinen What are the additional assumptions that I need?

Comment: @Soumee the correct statement is that $\mathsf P(A\mid B\cap C)=\mathsf P(A\mid C)$ iff $A$ and $B$ are *conditionally* independent given $C$.

Answer (score 8):

Not true, even if $A$ and $C$ are independent and $B$ and $C$ are independent.

Consider a sample space of $4$ equally likely outcomes $1,\ldots, 4$.
$A = \{1,2\}$, $B = \{1,3\}$, $C = \{1,4\}$.
$Pr(A|BC) = Pr(A|\{1\}) = 1$ but $Pr(A|C) = Pr(A|\{1,4\})=1/2$.

Answer (score 0):

The correct statement is that $\mathsf P(A\mid B\cap C)=\mathsf P(A\mid C)$ iff $A$ and $B$ are *conditionally* independent given $C$.

$$\begin{align}
\mathsf P(A\mid B\cap C)&=\dfrac{\mathsf P(A\cap B\cap C)}{\mathsf P(B\cap C)}
&&\text{by definition of conditional probability}
\\[1ex]
&=\dfrac{\mathsf P(A\cap B\mid C)~\mathsf P(C)}{\quad~~~\mathsf P(B\mid C)~\mathsf P(C)}
&&\text{by definition of conditional probability}
\\[1ex]
&=\dfrac{\mathsf P(A\mid C)~\mathsf P(B\mid C)~\mathsf P(C)}{\qquad\qquad\mathsf P(B\mid C)~\mathsf P(C)}
&&\text{by definition of conditional independence}&\star\\[1ex]
&={\mathsf P(A\mid C)}
&&\text{by cancelling common factors}\end{align}$$